# How to make multiple USABLE partitions on a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, usability

I have searched extensively and have not been able to find a working solution for my uses.

I have a SanDisk USB3.0 32Gb flash drive. I want to be able to have 2 partitions on it that are both readable and writable by Windows. So, when I insert the stick into a computer I would get 2 Autorun messages (Win 7) or 2 File Explorers (Win 10).

I know that this is possible because I have a video camera that when plugged in directly, two Explorers open. (*Unable to test with just SD card instead of directly, as a drop made the slot inaccessible*)

I've read that you can't do this in Windows using default software, but I have access to a Linux machine, and quite frankly prefer to use Linux.

First of all I would like to know if this is even possible using a generic USB stick, and if *Yes!* then how would I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible in windows.

1. Right click on my computer or my pc click manage, then navigate to disk management.
2. On the disk you want to make another partition for, right click and select shrink and shrink it by the amount that you want for the additional partition.
3. You will see that it makes some unallocated space. Simply right click on that unallocated space and click new simple volume and follow the wizard.

For Linux I'm not sure on the specifics but you can use gparted to do the same thing.

Comment: I already tried that, but no matter what format the drive is (FAT32, NTFS, exFAT), the Extend, Shrink, Add, and Delete options are always greyed out.

Comment: Windows disk management only supports NTFS and not FAT32 or exFAT. Have you tried reformatting to NTFS and trying again? If that doesn't work try following the solutions on this website: http://www.disk-partition.com/articles/shrink-volume-greyed-out-4125.html

Comment: Like I said above, NTFS didn't work. I will check out the site mentioned and tell of the results

Comment: Windows management works with all Windows supported file systems, including FAT32, exFAT... It just can't shrink filesystems other than NTFS. Use a 3rd party software like [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/), [MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/), [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html)... Those are free and much more easy to use, much more feature rich than Windows default one

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant